# How to get in Excel the Top 10 results from a list without duplicates?

Tags: excel, rank

I have a list of four columns in Excel, for which I would like to get the Top 10 results, in an ordered fashion (see right side of the screenshot below).

I am using

```
=IF(11 - RANK(B120; B$120:B$140) <= 0; ""; 11 - RANK(B120; B$120:B$140))
```

which works mostly fine. But then, it seems when there are duplicates (three times rank 1 as the values are identical - see third RANK column in the screenshot) then it doesn't count it as three but only as one entry:

[image]

Perhaps one way to go would be to work with an array? Having done that only a few times long time ago, I am not sure how this would work.

These are the data:

```
1998,0.63,0.618461538,0.548241758,0.597318681
1999,0.44,0.398461538,0.328241758,0.364318681
2000,0.42,0.398461538,0.328241758,0.352318681
2001,0.55,0.528461538,0.448241758,0.499318681
2002,0.6,0.618461538,0.488241758,0.554318681
2003,0.61,0.608461538,0.488241758,0.563318681
2004,0.58,0.528461538,0.448241758,0.505318681
2005,0.66,0.668461538,0.498241758,0.603318681
2006,0.61,0.608461538,0.488241758,0.564318681
2007,0.61,0.638461538,0.448241758,0.549318681
2008,0.54,0.508461538,0.378241758,0.453318681
2009,0.63,0.628461538,0.488241758,0.564318681
2010,0.7,0.698461538,0.528241758,0.618318681
2011,0.58,0.578461538,0.408241758,0.483318681
2012,0.62,0.608461538,0.478241758,0.528318681
2013,0.67,0.638461538,0.528241758,0.572318681
2014,0.74,0.728461538,0.598241758,0.637318681
2015,0.9,0.858461538,0.748241758,0.821318681
2016,0.95,0.978461538,0.778241758,0.855318681
2017,0.85,0.898461538,0.708241758,0.735318681
2018,0.79,0.818461538,0.638241758,0.653318681
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using math to rank these backwards? Rank has an optional parameter that would make *0.95* number 1, not number 10.

Comment: Yes, good question. It's true, I need the data in reversed order for the display in a graph later - 10 being the highest rank.